# Как скрыть псевдоэлемент за пределами родителя?

Tags: html, css

Нужно реализовать заливку кнопки **"под углом"**. Для этого использую `before`, который представляет собой прямоугольник, повернутый на определенный угол, размеры которого увеличиваются, если навести курсор на кнопку.

```css
.auth {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 20px 45px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #191919;
  /* background-color: #fff; */
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #191919;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear, color 0.2s linear;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  /* background-color: #191919; */
}

.button::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: -100%;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 0.2s linear, height 0.2s linear;
}

.button:hover::before {
  width: 160%;
  height: 250%;
}
```

```html
<div class="auth">
  <button class="button" type="submit">Войти</button>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы прямоугольник не отображался за пределами кнопки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

задай родителю `overflow: hidden`

```css
.auth {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 20px 45px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #191919;
  /* background-color: #fff; */
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #191919;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear, color 0.2s linear;
  overflow: hidden
}

.button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  /* background-color: #191919; */
}

.button::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: -100%;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 0.2s linear, height 0.2s linear;
}

.button:hover::before {
  width: 160%;
  height: 250%;
}
```

```html
<div class="auth">
  <button class="button" type="submit">Войти</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

не подойдет ли вам маскироване и клипирование?

https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css-masking-20121115/

http://htmlbook.ru/css/clip

Comment: Через `clip` пытался, не получилось (возможно в координатах запутался :D). свойство `overflow: hidden;` для `.button` решило проблему.